# Syntax error near unexpected token '{'

Tags: bash, autocomplete, syntax

Every time I run new virtual terminal, it starts with

```
bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 226: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 226: `}'
kimifish@kimipc:~$
```

But the file `bash_completion` seems to be оk (sure it's not though). *Sorry for those vertical bars, it's just vim tab highlight*:

```
     ...
     186 # Assign variables one scope above the caller
     187 # Usage: local varname [varname ...] &&
     188 #        _upvars [-v varname value] | [-aN varname [value ...]] ...
     189 # Available OPTIONS:
     190 #     -aN  Assign next N values to varname as array
     191 #     -v   Assign single value to varname
     192 # Return: 1 if error occurs
     193 # See: http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Passing_variables_by_reference
     194 _upvars()
     195 {
     196     if ! (( $# )); then
     197     |   echo "${FUNCNAME[0]}: usage: ${FUNCNAME[0]} [-v varname"\
     198     |   |   "value] | [-aN varname [value ...]] ..." 1>&2
     199     |   return 2
     200     fi
     201     while (( $# )); do
     202     |   case $1 in
     203             -a*)
     204     |   |   |   # Error checking
     205     |   |   |   [[ ${1#-a} ]] || { echo "bash: ${FUNCNAME[0]}: \`$1': missing"\
     206     |   |   |   |   "number specifier" 1>&2; return 1; }
     207     |   |   |   printf %d "${1#-a}" &> /dev/null || { echo "bash:"\
     208     |   |   |   |   "${FUNCNAME[0]}: \`$1': invalid number specifier" 1>&2
     209     |   |   |   |   return 1; }
     210     |   |   |   # Assign array of -aN elements 
     211     |   |   |   [[ "$2" ]] && unset -v "$2" && eval $2=\(\"\${@:3:${1#-a}}\"\) &&
     212     |   |   |   shift $((${1#-a} + 2)) || { echo "bash: ${FUNCNAME[0]}:"\
     213     |   |   |   |   "\`$1${2+ }$2': missing argument(s)" 1>&2; return 1; }
     214     |   |   |   ;;
     215             -v) 
     216     |   |   |   # Assign single value
     217     |   |   |   [[ "$2" ]] && unset -v "$2" && eval $2=\"\$3\" &&
     218     |   |   |   shift 3 || { echo "bash: ${FUNCNAME[0]}: $1: missing"\
     219     |   |   |   "argument(s)" 1>&2; return 1; }
     220     |   |   |   ;;
     221             *)  
     222     |   |   |   echo "bash: ${FUNCNAME[0]}: $1: invalid option" 1>&2
     223     |   |   |   return 1 ;;
     224         esac
     225     done
     226 }
     ...
```

and I have absolutely no idea where to look for an error…

Part of my `~/.bashrc` about bash-completion:

```
  91 if ! shopt -oq posix ; then
  92   if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
  93     . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  94   elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
  95     . /etc/bash_completion
  96   fi
  97 fi
```

Deleting code by parts revealed somewhat: cutting "`while`" loop eliminates the error, but cutting only "`case`" construction does not. =/

Comment: Is it possible that the file as some Microsoft CRLF line endings or other invisible characters? Check with `sed -n l < the-file`

Comment: If you *have absolutely no idea where to look for an error*  please consider leaving away parts of the function: Will it work without the `while` loop. If yes, just leave away single `case`s to narrow the problem and so on.

Comment: The error may point to the last `}` of the file, but the thing that caused it may be in the beginning of it (which isn't shown here).

Comment: One approach to debugging - copy the function to a file of its own (or build up the function in a file of its own) and in a new Bash, source that file alone; add/remove code until you find the cause.

Comment: Perhaps try quoting `"${1#-a}"`, too.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas No CRLFs in file, thx

Comment: @Kusalananda It is not last "}", and all other first-level {} above it are ok and not causing errors.

Comment: @ВладШерышев Ah, I didn't see the `...` at the end.

Comment: Deleting code by parts revealed somewhat: cutting "while" loop eliminates the error, but cutting only "case" construction does not. =/

Comment: If you _cut_ the  `case` construct, you have to replace it  with something else as the body of a while loop can't be empty.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yep, I've replaced it with `echo`

Comment: I can't reproduce on that code. Can you post a minimum reproducer? What version of `bash` is it?

Comment: Do you have aliases for some `bash` keyword like `done`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Damn it, yes! `unalias done`, and all gone. Never thought I would make such a trivial mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible explanation is that you do

```
alias done='something'
```

prior to sourcing `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`.

That would explain that error message as `bash` would complain about the function being closed while the `while` loop hasn't (because of the missing `done` that was replaced by `something`).

Don't use `done` or any shell keyword as an alias name (though you could  define some instrumenting aliases like `alias do='do ((loop_level++));'; alias done='((loop_level--)); done'` as long as they keep the shell structure).